# The requested URL /storesheet was not found on this server

Tags: html, angularjs

I am working with angularjs. I put link like this. `<li><a href="/storesheet">Store Sheet</a></li>`. I got error

> The requested URL /storesheet was not found on this server.

This is my config file.

```
.when("/storesheet", {
  templateUrl : "components/inventory/report.tpl.html",
  controller: 'reportCtrl as report',
})
```

Comment: try `href="#/storesheet"`

Comment: I put <li><a target="_self" href="#/storesheet">Store Sheet</a></li>. but still not working.

Comment: How does your `base` look like inside `index.html`? Also, in what order did you put your wildcard route (i.e. the `/` route)? Are there are any other pages that have similar names to /storesheet?

Comment: i included <script src="js/app.js"></script> in index.html file. app.config(['$provide', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 'authProvider', "$httpProvider", "jwtInterceptorProvider",
  function($provide, $routeProvider, $locationProvider, authProvider, $httpProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/storesheet", {
  templateUrl : "components/inventory/report.tpl.html",
  controller: 'reportCtrl as report',
})